# Add new directive instance recursively on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I am trying to create an Angular Directive that is recursively filled with data (loaded through $http) by clicking elements. 
At the beginning there should be only a button. Upon clicking the button, data is loaded from a remote source through $http, a new instance of the directive is created, compiled and appended to the parent instance for each child.
These child-directives are again buttons and should load and append their childrens data to them i.e the grandchildren are nested into the childrens' directive and so forth.

The code below loads and appends the first children correctly but clicking the appended directives will create new directives that are appended to the **root** directive. It seems that element.append() always refers to the root.

Does somebody know where I'm going wrong here?

```
app.directive('sectionloader',['$compile', 'sectionService', '$http', 
    function($compile, sectionService, $http){

    return  {
        restrict : 'E',
        template: '<button>loadSection</button><br>',
        scope : {sectionId:'@'}, 
        terminal: false,
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
                sectionService.loadBySectionId(attrs.sectionId, function(data){
                    var sectionHtmlLocation = "http://remoteserver/sectionhtml.html"
                    scope.section=data;
                    scope.subsections = [];
                    data.subsections.forEach(function(id){
                        sectionService.loadBySectionId(id,function(data){
                            scope.subsections.push(data);
                        });
                    });
                    $http.get(sectionHtmlLocation).success(function(data){
                    var compiledData = $compile(data)(scope.$new());
                    element.append(compiledData);

                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

The template that is compiled and attached is:

```
<div class="subsections">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subsection in subsections">
            {{subsection.sectionName}}
            <sectionloader sectionid="{{subsection.sectionId}}"></sectionloader>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Recursively? If it's triggered by a click it's not strictly recursive, is it? Recursion has to have a finite number of recursions or a termination clause. Maybe re title the question. Anyway you might not be catching the event at the source. Look at how you are triggering the event and stop the event from propagating... Might be a starting point.

Comment: Is your section html template static?

Comment: I guess my definition of recursion is not quite correct, nesting would have been a better choice of words. Anyways, you were absolutely right, the problem was the element.bind('click...) catching the event at the wrong location. It works fine when I add the click function to the scope and call it via ng-click in the button tag. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries. Ill write an answer when I get a spare moment and you can accept it if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how you are binding your clink event. You might not be catching the event at the intended source and it would then be propagating upwards to the parent...

Replacing the `bind` call with an `ng-click` solves the issue.

```
<button ng-click="load();">loadSection</button>
```

then declare load on the scope...

```
   $scope.load = function(){
       ...
   }
```